# Pull Site Code from Location Name (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a customer that need a specific code isolated from the name of each location. I have the following formula that I have been manually editing, but was wondering if there is a way to have it possibly count the characters in a cell and pull the codes to a new cell.

Example Location Name: MRI-LENOX HILL RADIOLOGY 150/14101

```
=RIGHT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-19)
```

The code format is 0123/01234 (3 to 4 characters in front of the slash and 5 after)

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Justin Hames

Comment: Is it always 3/5? You can just do =Right(A1, 9)

Comment: I just realized some codes have 4 digits before the slash, but if I were to user =Right(A1,10) would this work? There is always a space before the code i am trying to extract.

Comment: If there is only four sometimes 9 should still work. It will get the code if there is five and the space and code if there is four.  You can use =trim(Right(A1, 9)) to take off the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to find and extract the code from the cell value. For example:

```
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = "\d{3,4}/\d{5}"
    If .Test(Range("A1")) Then
        Range("B1") = .Execute(Range("A1"))(0)
    End If
End With
```

This will extract the code from `A1` and place it into `B1`.

**Edit**, with respect to comments:

To run on a range of cells:

```
Dim re
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.Pattern = "\d{3,4}/\d{5}"

Dim r As Range
For Each r In Range("A1:A100")
    If re.Test(r) Then r.Offset(0, 1) = re.Execute(r)(0)
Next
```

Comment: I will try this as well thank you for the quick response! :)

Comment: Should be a little more reliable in case the string has spaces at the end or other characters that throw off the character count. You could even wrap this into a custom worksheet function if you just wanted to use it in a formula.

Comment: Hmm for some reason it wont run the script. Any ideas as to why?    Sub Insert()

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = "\d{3,4}/\d{5}"
    If .test(Range("A12")) Then
        Range("B12") = .Execute(Range("A12"))(0)
    End If
End With

End Sub

Comment: Just paste it into a `Sub` (call it whatever you'd like) in your worksheet. Is that what you're trying?

Comment: Yep I paste it into a sub and click run and nothing seems to happen.

Comment: And you have a location name in `A1`? And nothing appears in `B1`?

Comment: Correct. I have the following data in A1 RADNET MGMT 10/90001

Comment: But that's _two_ digits, followed by five. You said it would be 3 or 4. You'll have to change the pattern to `\d{2,4}/\d{5}`.

Comment: Nevermind I got it... Had a derp moment and realized the code in A1 was incorrect it works now. Is there a way I can have it loop through a range and do this for all the needed cells? I have to do this with hundreds of locations.

Comment: Would i just change A1 to say A1:A100? and B1 to B1:B100?

Comment: Do you want to use it in VBA or as a worksheet function? Let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: prefer VBA. I have to do this on a regular basis, so I would rather just have a script I can drop into a module and run.

Comment: I've edited it to show how you can run on a specific range (`A1:A100`) and then throw the result into column B (by using `Offset(0, 1)` to shift over one column).